# Unable to import ActivityChooserModel

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, shareactionprovider

For some reason, I am unable to access the [`ActivityChooserModel`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e5c90287061d47f5ac9244dcc819778d4df9667c/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActivityChooserModel.java) class in my Android activity. I am trying to access it as follows:

```
ActivityChooserModel dataModel = ActivityChooserModel.get(this, ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
```

But when I try to build the project I get the following:

```
cannot find symbol class ActivityChooserModel
```

I have attempted using both of the following imports, but neither of them works:

```
import android.widget.ActivityChooserModel;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel;
```

This is especially frustrating because in Android Studio I can open `ActivityChooserModel.java` and I can see that it is a public class. My activity is using a `ShareActionProvider` and importing it with no problems, and when I browse through the SDK source I can clearly view both that class and `ActivityChooserModel` so I have no idea why I'm not able to access it.

Here is a snippet of my `build.gradle`, although I'm not sure if related:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It compiled for me.  Make sure you have `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1"` in your Gradle dependencies.

Comment: @DanielNugent ah thank you, that must be it! Unfortunately I can't add that right now due to some dependency conflicts, but once I do I will confirm whether that fixed the problem or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiled for me:

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityChooserModel dataModel = ActivityChooserModel.get(this, ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);

    }
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me, but I had to include `appcompat-v7` in my project in order to do so, and that's a pretty big library. Although very hacky, I discovered an alternative way to do it with reflection:

```
Class<?> activityChooserModel = Class.forName("android.widget.ActivityChooserModel");
Method activityChooserGetMethod = activityChooserModel.getMethod("get", Context.class, String.class);
Object activityChooserObject = activityChooserGetMethod.invoke(null, this, ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
```

The accepted answer is probably better if you don't mind including `appcompat-v7` but I just wanted to add this one as well